# Flex 3: Dynamic creation and binding of textinput

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Does anyone have any examples on how to create a dynamic number of `TextInput` boxes and have each of the text being typed in these boxes be bound to a label? For example, say I have an XML file that specifies that I want 3 `TextInput` boxes. Flex should then take this data, create the `TextInput` boxes, create bindable variables for each `TextInput` and create a label to display what is being typed for each `TextInput`. The biggest issue I'm having with solving this scenario is how to bind a variable amount of data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function creates a pair of textinput/label, where label.text is binded to data in textinput. This should be a good starting point for your code.

```
private function createTextFieldWithLabel ():void
{
    var tf:TextInput = new TextInput();
    var label:Label = new Label();
    var binding:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindProperty(label, "text", tf, "text");
    var hbox:HBox = new HBox();
    hbox.addChild(tf);
    hbox.addChild(label);
    addChild(hbox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new variable for each text input.  Just use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html) to create runtime binding.

Here's an article: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_7.html