# data binding with as3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, binding

I have a bit of a problem (since I'm not used to binding with AS3), the thing is that I want to do this kind of data binding:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="vertical"
    verticalAlign="middle"
    backgroundColor="white">

<mx:XML id="dp" source="countries_states_cities.xml" format="e4x" />

<mx:Form>
    <mx:FormItem label="Country:">
        <mx:ComboBox id="countryCB"
                dataProvider="{dp.country}"
                labelField="@name" />
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="State:">
        <mx:ComboBox id="stateCB"
                dataProvider="{countryCB.selectedItem.state}"
                labelField="@name" />
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="City:">
        <mx:ComboBox id="cityCB"
                dataProvider="{stateCB.selectedItem.city}"
                labelField="@name" />
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

but the ComboBoxes are being created dynamically with AS3, everything is working except I cant bind the second ComboBox dataProvider to be the XMLList in the first ComboBox's selectedItem.

Comment: Show us your AS3 code and let us know what approach you've tried and why it isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need runtime binding. It is done with [BindingUtils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html) class, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966047/flex-3-dynamic-creation-and-binding-of-textinput) for example. As for your case, it must be something like

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(secondCombobox, "dataProvider",
    firstCombobox, "selectedItem");
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating it dynamically based on data?  If so, you could always use the Repeater component to repeat what you're trying to accomplish.

```
<mx:Repeater dataProvider="{someData}">
    <mx:FormItem label="{data.label}">
        <mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{data.stateCB.selectedItem.city}"
                labelField="@name" />
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for, the code line that works for me is something like:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(comboBox, 'dataProvider', parentCB, {name: 'selectedItem', getter: function (host:ComboBox):XMLList {
                                var dp:XMLList;
                                if (host.selectedIndex >= 0) dp = host.selectedItem.children();
                                else dp = new XMLList();
                                return dp; 
                            }}, true);
```

However, I haven't been able to access the "site" inside the function, only the "host". Basically what I'm trying to do is make the second ComboBox start with selectedIndex = -1